# Dropzone js - maxFiles not working

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, dropzone.js

I am building a drag drop file upload using **dropzone.js**. The `maxFiles` configuration option works well when the files are uploaded for the first time. But when I display the already uploaded files and try to upload again, the `maxFiles` configuration is ignored.

I'm displaying the already uploaded files like this:

```
init: function() {
    var thisDropzone = this;
    track = getParameterByName('trackno');
    $.getJSON('get_upload_files.php?track='+track, function(data) { // get the json response
      $.each(data, function(key,value){ //loop through it
        var mockFile = { name: value.name, size: value.size }; // here we get the file name and size as response 
        thisDropzone.options.thumbnail.call(thisDropzone, mockFile, "uploads/"+value.name);//uploadsfolder is the folder where you have all those uploaded files
        thisDropzone.emit("addedfile", mockFile);
      });
    });
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is updating the `option.maxFiles` value once you know how many files have already been uploaded.

Let's say you want a maximum of 10 files, it will look like:

```
init: function() {
    var thisDropzone = this;
    track = getParameterByName('trackno');
    $.getJSON('get_upload_files.php?track='+track, function(data) { // get the json response
      $.each(data, function(key,value){ //loop through it
        var mockFile = { name: value.name, size: value.size }; // here we get the file name and size as response 
        thisDropzone.options.thumbnail.call(thisDropzone, mockFile, "uploads/"+value.name);//uploadsfolder is the folder where you have all those uploaded files
        thisDropzone.emit("addedfile", mockFile);
      });
      // update maxFiles
      thisDropzone.options.maxFiles = 10 - data.length;
    });
  }
```

Comment: I'm trying this solution, but unfortunately get an error: Uncaught ReferenceError: getParameterByName is not defined - Any idea what could be causing this? It looks like it is a custom function?